# [spring]channels attribute of <flex:remoting-destination> tag doesn't work

Tags: spring, apache-flex, flex3, blazeds

I configure blazeDS remote services by means of Spring.
I try override default channels for Remote service.

`<flex:remoting-destination ref="flexCustomerService" destination-id="customerService"
    channels="customers-channel-secure-amf, customers-channel-amf"/>`

But on runtime I get flex error
Server.Processing: Destination 'customerService' not accessible over channel 'channel-secure-amf'.

Comment: Are you trying to create your own custom AMF channel? Could you provide the code of channels you defined?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was about defining custom Channel sets on flex side. I defined all remote services in flex-servlet.xml,  which isn't use for compile flex. So I just added attribute channelSet to `<mx:RemoteObject>` to make flex know about custom channels tag on flex side.

`<mx:RemoteObject id="customerService" destination="customerService" fault="dispatchFaultEvent(event)"
                     makeObjectsBindable="true" channelSet="{customerServiceSet}"/>`